# Ehcache throws NullPointerException while evicting expired elements

Tags: java, ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

In `Ehcache`, to remove old entries I have enabled `timeToIdleSeconds`property.

Periodically, one process tries to remove all the expired elements from cache by calling `cache.evictExpiredElements()`

Cache Configuration:

```
 <cache name="cache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="100000" eternal="false" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="true" timeToIdleSeconds="60"/>
```

The following exception thrown during eviction (not always):

> EhCache: run(): catching java.lang.NullPointerException at net.sf.ehcache.store.offheap.disk.OffHeapDiskStore.expireElements(OffHeapDiskStore.java:348)
>   ~[ehcache-ee-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0] at
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore.expireElements(CacheStore.java:426)
>   ~[ehcache-ee-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0] at
>   net.sf.ehcache.Cache.evictExpiredElements(Cache.java:2986)
>   ~[ehcache-ee-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Offheap in Ehcache 2.9.x is an enterprise feature, you are better off contacting support.